# term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments--error

Tags: c++, stl, heap

hi I am using make_heap in my cpp program. I have written below code corresponding to it-

```
struct jobs {
int abs_deadline, id, rem_ET, arr_time;
};
struct compareDeadline {
bool comparator(jobs t1, jobs t2) {     
        return t1.abs_deadline < t2.abs_deadline;
}
};
struct compareArrTime {
bool comparator( jobs t1,  jobs t2) {
    return t1.arr_time < t2.arr_time;
}
};
void runningPhase(int ntasks,vector<tasks> j) {
vector<jobs> ready_queue,waiting_queue;                            
int system_criticality = 1, temp, timer = j[0].arr_time;
cout << "\nSCHEDULE:\n\n";
for (int i = 1; i <ntasks; i++) {
    if (j[i].criticality == 1) {
        temp = j[i].arr_time + j[i].deadline;
        if (timer == j[i].arr_time) {               
            ready_queue.push_back({ temp,j[i].id, j[i].wcet[0],j[i].arr_time });
        }
        else {
            waiting_queue.push_back({ temp,j[i].id,j[i].wcet[0],j[i].arr_time });
        }
    }
}
make_heap(ready_queue.begin(), ready_queue.end(), compareArrTime());
make_heap(waiting_queue.begin(), waiting_queue.end(), compareDeadline());
schedule(j, ready_queue, waiting_queue,ntasks);
}
```

Getting attached error 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XL6U.png)

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Please include the full error in your question

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an argument of type `compareArrTime` to `make_heap`. That's fine.
Let's call it `cat`.  Inside `make_heap`, it will try to call it thus: `cat(one, two)`.

But your `compareArrTime` doesn't have an `operator ()` defined.
Hence the error.

You should write it thus:

```
struct compareArrTime {
bool operator ()( jobs t1, jobs t2) const {
    return t1.arr_time < t2.arr_time;
}
};
```

and probably take `t1` and `t2` by `const &` rather than by value.

Comment: i have changed code as below-
struct compareArrTime {
 bool operator()(const jobs &t1, const jobs &t2) {
  return t1.arr_time < t2.arr_time;
 }
};
 now i am getting attached errors 
1.Error C2672 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found 
2. C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) noexcept(<expr>) const' 
3.Error C2056 illegal expression